# Python sqlalchemy mysql .where clause on a date

Tags: python, select, sqlalchemy

I have the following code which selects all records with the speciific ticker which works but im also trying to filter on the records past a specific date but it doesnt work it returns all records of that ticker and ignores the date condition, anyone help with this?

```
engine = get_engine()
metadata = MetaData(bind=engine)
session = sessionmaker(bind=engine)()
table = Table('market_data', metadata, autoload=True, autoload_with=engine)
stmt = select([table]).where(and_(table.columns.date > '2019-01-01',
                                  table.columns.ticker == ticker
                                  ))

fields = ['date', 'ticker', 'high', 'low', 'open', 'close', 'volume', 'adj_close']
stocks = session.query()

connection = engine.connect()
results = connection.execute(stmt).fetchall()

return results
```

Comment: can you share us how is schema table and the type ?...